# Loop issue with use of if statement

Tags: java

I have this hangman program but have an issue with asking the user if they want to play again, it always just ends the program. How can i fix this issue. Thanks for future reply's.
package hangman. I hope editing is okay with this

import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Hangman {

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static int size, size2;
static boolean play = false;
static String word;
static String[] ARRAY = new String[0];
static String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
static String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
static String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
static String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
static String ANSI_LIGHTBLUE = "\u001B[36m";
//^declarations for variables and colors for display^

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    randomWordPicking();
     //^calls method^
 }

 public static void setUpGame() {

    System.err.printf("Welcome to hangman.\n");

    try {

        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new    File("H:\\HangMan\\src\\hangman\\HangMan.txt"));
        String line;
        while (scFile.hasNext()) {
            line = scFile.nextLine();
            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line);
            size++;
        }
        ARRAY = new String[size];
        Scanner scFile1 = new Scanner(new File("H:\\HangMan\\src\\hangman\\HangMan.txt"));
        while (scFile1.hasNext()) {
            String getWord;
            line = scFile1.nextLine();
            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line);
            word = scLine.next();
            ARRAY[size2] = word;
            size2++;
  //calls method for picking word^
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
 }

 public static void randomWordPicking() {


    setUpGame();

    int LEFT = 6;

    do {

        int random = (int) (Math.random() * ARRAY.length);

        //^genertates a random number^


        String randomWord = ARRAY[random];
        String word = randomWord;

        //^chosses a random word and asgins it to a variable^

        char[] ranWord = randomWord.toCharArray();

        char[] dash = word.toCharArray();

        //^Creates a char array for the random word chosen and for the dashs which are displayed^



        for (int i = 0; i < dash.length; i++) {
            dash[i] = '-';

            System.out.print(dash[i]);

            //^displays dashs to the user^
        }

        for (int A = 1; A <= dash.length;) {

            System.out.print(ANSI_BLUE + "\nGuess a Letter: " + ANSI_RESET);
            String userletters = keyboard.next();

            //^gets user input^

            if (!userletters.equalsIgnoreCase(randomWord)) {

                //^allows program to enter loop if user has entered a letter^
                for (int i = 0; i < userletters.length(); i++) {

                    char userLetter = userletters.charAt(i);

                    String T = Character.toString(userLetter);

                    for (int B = 0; B < ranWord.length; B++) {

                        //^converts users input to a char and to a string^    
                        if (userLetter == dash[B]) {

                            System.err.println("This " + userLetter + "' letter already exist");
                            B++;
                            //^tells user if the letter they entered already exists^
                            if (userLetter == dash[B - 1]) {
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (userLetter == ranWord[B]) {
                            dash[B] = userLetter;
                            A--;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!(new String(ranWord).contains(T))) {
                        LEFT--;
                        System.out.println("You did not guess a correct letter, you have " + LEFT + " OF "
                                + dash.length + " trys left to guess correctly");
                    }
                    //^shows how many trys the user has left to get the word right before game ends^
                    System.out.println(dash);
                    if (LEFT == 0) {
                        System.out.println("The word you had to guess was " + word);
                        break;
                    }
                    //^shows the user the word if they didnt guess correctly^
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "\nYou have guessed the word correctly!" + ANSI_RESET);
                break;
            }
            if (LEFT == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if ((new String(word)).equals(new String(dash))) {
          System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "\nYou have guessed the word correctly!" + ANSI_RESET);
                break;
            }
        }
    //^if user enters the word it will check and then display that they got the word correct^
        System.out.println("Play agian? (y/n)");
        String name = keyboard.next();
        //^asks user if they want to play again^
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            play = true;
            return;
        }

        //^stops program if user enters n to stop game^
     } while (play = false);

 }
```

}

Comment: As far as I understand you want to call method `playOn()`. I however do not see where do you call it.

Comment: @AlexR I put the code from the method, to where it should have been

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
while (!play)
```

instead of

```
while (play = false)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare two variables, do not use `=` operator, which means assignment. Use `==` instead. Additionally, in your case it should be `!=`:

```
while (play != false)
```